# DHCPv6 returns a /128 mask

Tags: ipv6

I have a dhcp server (dnsmask) running and working.
But my clients receive a /128 ipv6 address. Like that :

```
 inet6 fd00:cafe:cafe:cafe::4246/128 scope global dynamic
```

Shouldn't i get a /64 mask ?

Here is my dnsmask conf :

```
interface=wlx503eaa3d7d6c
no-dhcp-interface=lo, eth0
dhcp-range=fd00:cafe:cafe:cafe::10,fd00:cafe:cafe:cafe::cafe,12h
port = 0
enable-ra
```

So did i miss something ?

Thanks

Comment: My guess would be that it is because the question is about host configuration (off-topic) rather than programming (on-topic). [sf], [su], or [unix.se] would seem to be better fits for the question.

Answer (score 0):

answer :

```
dhcp-range=fd00:cafe:cafe:cafe::,ra-only
```

then i get a /64 mask

MAN page (http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) :

```
--dhcp-range=::,constructor:eth0

 For IPv6, the mode may be some combination of ra-only, slaac, ra-names, ra-stateless, ra-advrouter, off-link.

ra-only tells dnsmasq to offer Router Advertisement only on this subnet, and not DHCP.
```

Answer (score 0):

/sbin/dhcpcd has a "-U" option that dumps all info about the leased assigned by your ISP.  Using the "-4" and "-6" options, the IPv4 and IPv6 can be queried.  The information is dumped in bash script format that can be "grep'ed".

dnsmasq allows the reading of all files in a directory at start, so I write the network requirements when the script is run.  I have reserved 1-500 IPv6 addresses for my own private use that are not advertised.

The script also pulls the fe80:: address for my firewall machine so that dnsmasq will advertise the router when dhcp request is required from a computer or phone.

I also set my MTU to 1412.  Look at the man page for "man pppoe".  In notes at the bottom there is a discussion of 1412. I don't have Netflix video stream drop outs anymore.

I have built my own RPI-4 firewall machine with an added USB dongle Ethernet. I run the following script to pull my ISP info.

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

base_prefix=$(/sbin/dhcpcd -6 -U eth0 | grep "dhcp6_ia_pd1_prefix1=" | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -d : -f 1-4 | cut -d "'" -f 2)

#   echo $base_prefix

# following sets up router advertizements for dnsmasq

# ie: dnsmasq reads this file to get the ipv6 network ip6 base prefix numbers

echo "dhcp-range="$base_prefix":0:0:0:500,"$base_prefix":FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF, ra-names, 150" >/etc/dnsmasq.d/router-advertise.conf

# scanned from iptables enx0050b6eab7d6 device

link_ip=$(ip address show dev enx0050b6eab7d6 scope link | awk /inet6 / {split($2,var,"/"); print var[1]}')

echo "dhcp-option=option6:dns-server,[${link_ip}]"  >/etc/dnsmasq.d/local-dns-server.conf


/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart

exit 0
```

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions